# Branch pointing to an old commit

Tags: git

I'm working on a project which had some failing tests, so I decided to checkout an old commit to take a look at the code changes that might have caused the issue. I did `git checkout OLD_COMMIT_HASH`. This was fine, however I can't seem to get the branch to default to the latest branch anymore.

I've done `git checkout LATEST_COMMIT_HASH`, but if I then checkout master and do `git checkout BRANCH_NAME` it checks out the old commit, how do I fix the branch and point it to the correct commit?

Comment: The first question should be why `git checkout BRANCH_NAME` would be behaving in the way you describe.  If `BRANCH_NAME` was on `LATEST_COMMIT_HASH` and you said `git checkout OLD_COMMIT_HASH`, this would not change the behavior of `git checkout BRANCH_NAME`; it would still point to `LATEST_COMMIT_HASH`.  I could guess at what else happened, and based on that guess I'd say Jean Carlo Machado's answer is on the right track.  But without a more complete account of what created the current problem, we're only able to make assumptions about what the current state is - much less how to fix it.

Comment: First time I read I thought I understood your question. Now I'm not sure anymore, so I dropped my answer. Try to clarify each step you made and where you want to go.

Comment: Did you use reset at any point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you checkout on a commit hash you are not a branch, you are just in a twilight zone that points to that particular commit, somewhere in the history of your branch.

Just `git checkout <branch_name>` to get back to your branch.

You also get a message when checking out on a commit that explains that you are in a "detached" state, meaning you are not on any branch:

> You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
>   changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
>   state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.
>
> If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
>   do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late for this right now, but in a future if you find yourself simply wanting to go back to previously checked out code in git. You can just do:

```
git checkout -
```

So if you were on a HEAD of master and you run `git checkout OLD_COMMIT_HASH`, if you just run `git checkout -` you will go back to HEAD of master

But for now, just go with @Jean's answer